# What is $x + \Theta(x^2)+ \Theta(x)$ , when $x$ goes to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Q: if $f(x) = x + \Theta(x^2)$ and $g(x)=\Theta(x)>0$. What is $f(x) + g(x)$ when $x\rightarrow 0$.

I'm confused because I read some articles that if the x is going to zero, the Big-theta notation follows the smallest one. And I am not sure that I can manipulate Big-theta notation from other functions. So some solutions come up to my head, I just don't know which one is correct.

The multiple answers that I can assume:

$\Theta(x^2)$

$\Theta(x^2)+x$

$\Theta(x^2)+\Theta(x)+x$

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume for simplicity $f,g \geqslant 0$, then we have
$$\left\{\begin{array}{}
x+C_1x^2 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant x+C_2x^2 \\
A_1x \leqslant g(x) \leqslant A_2x
\end{array} \right\} \Rightarrow x+C_1x^2 +A_1x \leqslant f(x)+g(x)\leqslant x+C_2x^2+A_2x $$
Now you can write estimation in different variants: $\Theta(x) \supset  x+\Theta(x)\supset x+\Theta(x)+\Theta(x^2)$.

Comment: Thank you!, so the answer should be expressed with the ⊆ notation? Not the single answer like Θ(x)?

Comment: @Devep. Why not - how it can be forbidden? I cannot write $f \in A \subset B$? For example $f \in C^{1}[0,1] \subset C[0,1]$. I wrote 3 step from more exact estimation up to less exact.  It's possible to write also more wide set, for example $\Theta(x) \subset \Theta(1), x \to 0$. It is same, that if function tends to $0$ in some point, then it is also bounded in that point some neigbourhood.  But we loss exactness and reverse sentence is not ture.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ goes toward zero, $x^2$ will be less than $x$. Hence, the final result will be $(x + \Theta(x) + \Theta(x^2)) \subseteq \Theta(x)$ when $x \to 0$ ($\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x + \Theta(x) + \Theta(x^2)}{x} = c \neq 0$)

Comment: Possible typo: you need "$\subset$" in place of "$\in$".

Comment: @zkutch thanks. Right.

Comment: So, the answer should be expressed with the ⊆ notation? Not the single answer like Θ(x)?

Comment: @Devep. No. By definition you can write the expression is $\Theta(x)$.